# Finding all strings that have single quotes with resharper 8

Tags: javascript, resharper, highlighting, code-cleanup, code-standards

We have some coding standards that state we must use double quotes instead of single quotes for string literals in JavaScript. As I am in the habit of always typing single quotes I was wondering if there was a way, using resharper 8, that I could either highlight all single quoted strings as an error using the custom highlighting (I did have a go at this but didn't get very far) or customising the code clean-up tool to auto replace single quotes with double quotes on code clean. If anyone can help with this, that would be great!

Comment: I think no way currently. I've added an issue here http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-403138, feel free to vote for it

Comment: Great cheers. Not sure why people have voted to close the question as it is not out of scope according to the guidelines: " but if your question generally covers… software tools commonly used by programmers", resharper is software tool used by programmers (http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Be handy if someone who voted to close gave an explanation.

Comment: @DmitryOsinovskiy can you add your comment as an answer and I will then accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think no way currently. I've added an issue here http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-403138, feel free to vote for it.